# arXiv compiles successfully, but the resulting pdf is missing the figures

Tags: floats, arxiv

I am trying to upload a paper to arXiv. 
The project passes the compilation stage successfully, but the resulting pdf is missing all figures (see below).

When compiling locally I end up with a proper pdf with all figures appearing.

Has anyone ran into this issue before?

[image]

---

Some other information that may be useful to diagnose the situation:

1. When using arXiv, I added `,natwidth=610,natheight=642` to my figures (it wouldn't compile without it).
2. I added a `\pdfoutput=1` command, as otherwise it is not able to successfully convert to pdf.
3. The log produced by arXiv only refers to each figure once, simply mentioning its file type (.png in this case).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Is a log file produced that can be examined?

Comment: @egreg - arXiv indeed produces a log, but I didn't find anything useful there. It pretty much said that the figures are png files and that was their only mention. I added some information that may be useful here.

Comment: the log is more likely to be useful to people answering the question than asking it:-). If you are using pdflatex at axiv you shouldn't need natwidth=... and if you are not using pdftex then most likely the png will not work, the log file would show such details.